# Behavior of LDR on a uint8_t variable in ARM?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm, gnu

I cannot find a straight answer for this anywhere. The registers for ARM are 32-bit, I know that LDRB loads a byte size value into a register and zeros out the remaining 3 bytes, even if you feed it a value bigger than a byte, it will just take the first byte value.

My program combines C with ARM Assembly. I have an extern variable in C that gets loaded into a register directly.

However if I call just LDR on this byte variable, is there a guarantee that it loads the byte and nothing else or will it load random things in the remaining 3 byte space from nearby things in memory to fill out the entire 32-bit register?

I'm only asking because I did LDR R0, =var and always got the correct value out of probably a hundred million executions (software ran for a long time and was tested thoroughly / recompiled many times before this issue was brought up on another setup).

However someone else with a different setup (Not so different, compiler is the same version I think) compiled the code successfully however the value loaded into R0 was polluted with random bits from the surrounding memory of the variable. They had to do LDRB to fix it.

Is this a compiler thing? Can it detect this and automatically switch it to LDRB? Or am I just that lucky that the surrounding memory of the variable was just zero due to some optimization?

As a side note the compiler is ARM GCC 9.2.1

Comment: Yes, you were just lucky. It's even worse for stores, you would be corrupting something else unnoticed. If your variable is 1 byte in size, use 1 byte load-store.

Comment: LDR doesn't know anything about how you declared the variable or what's supposed to be in the 4 bytes it loads.  That's why ISAs like ARM have byte loads like LDRB (and its sign-extending equivalent) in the first place.  And no, compilers don't waste 3 bytes after every `uint8_t` just so you can use word loads on it, that would be silly.

Comment: show the code and/or disassembly and we can explain it to you

Answer (score 2):

> because I did `LDR R0, =var`

Are you loading the **value** or the **address** of the variable?

Normally, the instruction `LDR R0, =var` will write the address of the variable `var` into the register `R0` and not the value.

And the address of a variable is always a 32-bit value on a 32-bit ARM CPU - independent of the data type.

> However if I call just `LDR` on this byte variable, ...

If you load the **value** of a variable (e.g. using `LDR R1, [R0]`), two things may happen:

- The upper 24 bits of the register may contain a random value depending on the bytes that follow your variable in memory. If you are lucky, the bytes are always zero.
- Depending on the exact CPU type, you may get problems due to alignment (for example an alignment exception or even completely undefined behavior)

Comment: *or even completely undefined behavior* Or on ARM, well-defined behaviour of using the low 2 bits of the address as a rotate count!!  IIRC, some early ARMvsomething does that.

Answer (score 0):

LDR doesn't know anything about how you declared the variable or what's supposed to be in the 4 bytes it loads. That's why ISAs like ARM have byte loads like LDRB (and its sign-extending equivalent) in the first place.

And no, compilers don't waste 3 bytes (of zeros) after every `uint8_t` just so you can use word loads on it, that would be silly.  i.e. `sizeof(uint8_t)` = 1 = unsigned char, `CHAR_BIT` = 8, and `alignof(uint8_t)` = 1

LDR loads an `int32_t` or `uint32_t` whole word.

But as Martin points out, `LDR r0, =var` puts the address of `var` into a register.
*Then* you use `ldrb r1, [r0]`

Fun fact: early ARM CPUs (ARMv4 and earlier) with an unaligned word load will use the low 2 bits of the address as a rotate count (after loading from an aligned word).  https://medium.com/@iLevex/the-curious-case-of-unaligned-access-on-arm-5dd0ebe24965